# jQuery: lightweight way to write and read parameters to URL hash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, jquery-plugins

I'm using jQuery and I'd like a lightweight plugin to write and read hash parameters from a URL.

For example, I'd like to be able to read a URL like `index.html#color=red&day=monday` and get `{ color: 'red', day: 'monday' }`.

I'd also like to be able to write parameters to the hash, checking for the presence of a variable, and adding or updating it as appropriate.

Does anyone know a *lightweight* plugin that can do this, or do I need to write my own?

Obviously [BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) does all of this and much more, but I don't need all the history management, and I'm loath to include a lot of code I don't need.

Answer (score 3):

this will work, you can put it in a function or use it straight forwardly:

```
  var hash = top.location.hash.replace('#', '');
    var params = hash.split('&');
    var result = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < params.length; i++){
       var propval = params[i].split('=');
       result[propval[0]] = propval[1];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - I have some code like that already. The tricky bit is writing to the URL, checking if a variable is already present or not. I was hoping there might be a plugin, but if not I guess I'll just write something custom.

Answer (score 2):

[purl](https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl) can read fragment params:

```
$.url("index.html#color=red&day=monday").fparam("color"); // returns "red"
```

To write them you can use jquery's `$.param()` helper. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drskot/8Dyeb/)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of a plugin that is lightweight, but you could use something like

```
    var hashdata = new Object();

    jQuery.each(window.location.hash.replace(/^#/,'').split('&'), function(i,t){

       var s = t.split('=');
       hashdata[s[0]] = s[1];

   });
```

Which if i'm correct should return an object of the hash data in the url. Then knowing the current hash data, you could use window.location.hash to change that as and when you want